# Other Computer Show Input String was not in correct format

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have problem installing VB.NET application to other Computer.

When Button Add is pressed and Choose item, the program say Input String was not in correct format.
my Datatable Declare is Here :

```
Private Sub prvFillDT()
        dtSales = New DataTable
        dtSales.Columns.Add("no", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("goodscode", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("goodsname", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("information", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("qty", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("price", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("discount", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))
        dtSales.Columns.Add("total", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))
End Sub
```

And Here is The Button Add Code

```
Dim arrFields() As String = {"GoodsCode", "GoodsName", "Stock", "UnitPrice"}
Dim kn As SqlConnection = OpenKNS(Settings.ConnectionString)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("usp_is_Goods_SLC_01", kn)
If fLookup.GetLookUpSP("List Goods", cmd, arrFields, "", "") Then
    Try
        If fLookup.pubLookUpDone Then
            If arrFields(2) = "0" Then
                MsgBox(arrFields(1) & " stock is not enough !")
                   Exit Sub
            End If
            bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "goodscode", arrFields(0))
            bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "goodsname", arrFields(1))
            bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "qty", 1)
            bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "price", arrFields(3))
            bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "total", 1 * arrFields(3))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "goodscode", "")
    bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "goodsname", "")
    bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "qty", 0)
    bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "price", 0)
    bndReport2.SetRowCellValue(bndReport2.FocusedRowHandle, "total", 0)
    End Try
    bndReport2.UpdateSummary()
End If
```

Here the Storedprocedure :

```
SELECT GoodsCode,GoodsName,Stock,
CONVERT(varchar,UnitPrice,1) UnitPrice 
FROM Ms_Goods WHERE [Status]=1
```

The problem is only show on other computer but mine is no problem is the problem on the Code or The Computer ?

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what line the exception was thrown on and what the actual input string was when it happened.

Comment: The likely culprit is different date or number format settings on different machines while the code is assuming a specific format. That's just an educated guess though, based on other times I've seen that error message and the fact that it is not happening everywhere. We need all the relevant information to be sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I already find my own answer after testing some sample.

The Answer for this question is because Region & Language my Computer using English (United States) and other Computer using different format like (Indonesian, India, Singapore and etc.)